# Order Status Category Field is required but not creatable

Tags: order, standard-field

The standard [Order object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/) has a Status picklist field defined as follows:

> Picklist of values that indicate order status. Each value is within
>   one of two status categories defined in StatusCode. For example, the
>   status picklist might contain Draft, Ready for Review, and Ready for
>   Activation values with a StatusCode of Draft.

There is also a StatusCode (Status Category) field defined as follows:

> The status category for the order. An order can be either Draft or
>   Activated. Label is Status Category.

Each Status is categorised as being a Draft status or an Activated status. (This is similar to Opportunity Stages being classified as Won / Closed (IsWon).)

The documentation states that the Order can be activated by setting the Status field to an Activated state:

> The application can subsequently activate an order by updating it and
>   setting the value in its Status field to an Activated state; however,
>   the Status field is the only field you can update when activating the
>   order.

After running the apex code below

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult stCodeDesc = Order.StatusCode.getDescribe();
System.debug('Order.StatusCode');
System.debug('isCreateable? '+stCodeDesc.isCreateable());
System.debug('isNillable? '+stCodeDesc.isNillable());
System.debug('isCalculated? '+stCodeDesc.isCalculated());
```

we got this DEBUG output:

```
11:19:39:003 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|Order.StatusCode
11:19:39:004 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|isCreateable? false
11:19:39:004 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|isNillable? false
11:19:39:004 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|isCalculated? false
```

**Question:**
How the StatusCode field is populated behind the scenes? 
With a custom code (outside salesforce) for validating the records creation before calling the API, we validate user inputs and as StatusCode is mandatory in theory (isNillable=false), so we put it as mandatory, and when a value is put for StatusCode I got the error:

> Unable to create/update fields: StatusCode. Please check the security
>   settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your
>   profile or permission set.

I believe that it is because of the field is not Createable, I just want to understand why this field is not a Calculated field from a technical perspective.

Comment: I agree with you. Therefore I've raised an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdow0UAB/status-category-metadata-support)